# How to trigger garbage collection?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, adobe, stagevideo

Does anyone know if it's possible to apply garbage collection to the new StageVideo component in AS3?  I have tried with no success!  Code is below:

```
if ( this._stageVideo == null )
{
    this._stageVideo = stage.stageVideos[0];
    this._stageVideo.addEventListener(StageVideoEvent.RENDER_STATE, stageVideoStateChange);
}
```

Attempt at GC:

```
this._stageVideo = null;
this._stageVideo.removeEventListener(StageVideoEvent.RENDER_STATE, stageVideoStateChange);
```

Comment: There is no such thing as "applying garbage collection", you can only prepare objects to be garbage collected by removing all event listeners and references to the object. Therefore, it would be nice if you would show some code

Answer (score 1):

```
this._stageVideo = null;
this._stageVideo.removeEventListener(StageVideoEvent.RENDER_STATE, stageVideoStateChange)
```

I'm surprised that it worked, it should throw an exception, you should first remove event listeners and then nullify it's reference.

Garbage collector does not start every time you nullify something, but if you can use Flash Builder profiler you can attempt to force GC, also if you want to test it out, you can package project as AIR, and call GC manually.

There is bug/feature that will invoke GC if you fail to start LocalConnection twice (http://www.nbilyk.com/flash-garbage-collection):

```
try {
    new LocalConnection().connect('foo');
    new LocalConnection().connect('foo');
} catch (e:Error) {}
```

Comment: Yes your right @nirth it shouldn't work, StageVideo works differently to normal display objects, so this is where I am getting confused!  Any suggestions from anyone who knows SV well?

Comment: Ok my bad, I got so involved in trying to garbage collect StageVideo I missed removing an event listener elsewhere!